# "A definition for the symbol could not be located" error with .shader in vs

Tags: visual-studio, shader, hlsl

Just created my first shader in Unity, got default Unlit code, and I can't refactor rename in .shader file in Visual Studio because of "A definition for the symbol could not be located" error. Happens both with ctrl+R and with left mouse click. Also occurrs for "Go to definition" and similar commands.

Also, if I just click on struct name e.g., VS doesn't highlight other references to this name.
In plain .cs files everything works perfectly.

[error and default code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdx14.png)

[.cs file meanwhile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl6ec.png)